# Can't reach returning function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with reaching the code of function that is returned by my 'main' function. Can anyone help me resolve this?

```js
function createBook() {
    let cnt = 1;


 return function(selector,tiTle,auThor,rate){
        alert("In");

    }
}
```

When I debug the code the returning function is passed.

Comment: If you're curious, this type of concept is called 'currying'. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a call of the returned function to call the function inside.

```js
function createBook() {
    let cnt = 1;
    return function (selector, tiTle, auThor, rate) {
        alert("In");
    }
}

// you need a call of the returned function to call the function inside
createBook()();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just calling `createBook()`, which returns an unexecuted function. You would need to execute the function that is returned by `createBook()` with another `()`:

```
createBook()();
```

Answer (score 1):

just call it as `createBook()()`

```js
function createBook() {
    let cnt = 1;
    return function(selector,tiTle,auThor,rate){
        alert("In");
    }
}

createBook()();
```

`createBook()` returns the `function` reference, you need to invoke it again with extra parenthesis `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Call the returned function

```js
function createBook() {
  let cnt = 1;

  return function(selector, tiTle, auThor, rate) {
    alert("In");

  }
}

createBook()()
```

alternatively

```js
function createBook() {
  let cnt = 1;

  return function(selector, tiTle, auThor, rate) {
    alert("In");

  }
}

var book = createBook();
// call anonymous function returned from `createBook()`
book();
```